# Unexpected keyword argument in python click

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-click

```
@click.group(context_settings=dict(help_option_names=['-h', '--help']))
def plot_glm():
    pass

@plot_glm.command()
@click.argument('path_nc')
@click.argument('out_path')
@click.argument('var_name')
@click.option('--xaxis_min', default=0.0, help='')
@click.option('--xaxis_max', default=1.1, help='')
@click.option('--xaxis_step', default=0.1, help='')
@click.option('--annotate_date', help='')
@click.option('--yr', default=0, help='')
@click.option('--date', default=-1, help='')
@click.option('--xlabel', default='', help='')
@click.option('--title', default='', help='')
@click.option('--tme_name', default='time', help='')
@click.option('--show_plot', help='')
@click.option('--any_time_data', help='')
@click.option('--format', default='%.2f', help='')
@click.option('--land_bg', help='')
@click.option('--cmap', default=plt.cm.RdBu, help='')
@click.option('--grid', help='')
@click.option('--fill_mask', help='')
def plot_map_from_nc(path_nc, out_path, var_name, xaxis_min=0.0, xaxis_max=1.1, xaxis_step=0.1,
                     annotate_date=False, yr=0, date=-1, xlabel='', title='', tme_name='time', show_plot=False,
                     any_time_data=True, format='%.2f', land_bg=True, cmap=plt.cm.RdBu, grid=False, fill_mask=False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    plot_glm()
```

I get this error when using python click library (python version 2.7.11, windows 10, click version 6.6):

```
    ctx = Context(self, info_name=info_name, parent=parent, **extra)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'any_time_data'
```

What can I do to fix this error?

Comment: please remove every option not regarding the 'any_time_data' option from your example code and  check the syntax

Comment: hmm, not sure how that would help. I would like to retain the other options.

Comment: it would help because some of them are bound to a third module and the first thing happening on execution is first a syntax error and then a NameError, not the TypeError you are getting.

Comment: Cannot reproduce your error message on _Click 6.6, python2.7.10, win7_. But I observe another error: `plt.cm.RdBu` is a bound method which takes one argument. So it should be changed to `lambda : plt.cm.RdBu(10)`. After fixing this, your code runs normally on my machine.

Comment: thanks @gdlmx, I changed to `plt.cm.RdBu(10)` but still getting the same error

Comment: By no way should `any_time_data` go to the `__init__` constructor of `Context`. I don't know how it happens on your machine. It may help if you post the full traceback of your error message.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems that you try to call `plot_map_from_nc` or `plot_glm` with actual arguments somewhere in your code like this:

```
plot_map_from_nc(any_time_data=False)
plot_glm(any_time_data=False)
```

which will generate the same error message that you got.

```
  File "testClick.py", line 39, in <module>
    plot_glm(any_time_data=False)
  File "c:\winPython\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 716, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\winPython\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 695, in main
    with self.make_context(prog_name, args, **extra) as ctx:
  File "c:\winPython\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 618, in make_context
    ctx = Context(self, info_name=info_name, parent=parent, **extra)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'any_time_data'
```

#### Reason for the error

That is because `plot_map_from_nc` and `plot_glm` are not normal functions after those `click` decorators. They are *callable objects*, whose signature becomes

```
plot_map_from_nc(args=None, prog_name=None, complete_var=None, standalone_mode=True, **extra)
```

The type of `plot_map_from_nc` is `click.core.Command` and every arguments passed to it will be redirected to `click.core.Command.main()`

#### Solution

The correct way to invoke these callable objects is

```
plot_map_from_nc(sys.argv[1:]) # or
plot_map_from_nc()
```

If you want to use `plot_map_from_nc` normally in your code, define it with a different name:

```
def __plot_map_from_nc__(... , any_time_data=True, ...):
    do_your_job_here
# create an alias
plot_map_from_nc = __plot_map_from_nc__ 
# pass this alias to click
@plot_glm.command()
@click.argument('path_nc') # ...
@click.option('--xaxis_min', default=0.0, help='') # ...
plot_map_from_nc

# Now  plot_map_from_nc becomes a   'click.core.Command'   object  while
# __plot_map_from_nc__ is still a normal function which can be invoke as
__plot_map_from_nc__(... , any_time_data=True, ...)
```

Comment: Looking back at the OP code, he has:

`def plot_map_from_nc(path_nc, out_path, var_name, xaxis_min=0.0, xaxis_max=1.1, xaxis_step=0.1,
                     annotate_date=False, yr=0, date=-1, xlabel='', title='', tme_name='time', show_plot=False,
                     any_time_data=True, format='%.2f', land_bg=True, cmap=plt.cm.RdBu, grid=False, fill_mask=False)`

which is syntactically incorrect (i.e. not `def foo(bar):`) or that is where `plot_map_from_nc` is being called with the argument as you suggest in your answer.

Comment: @busfault : You're correct, the OP code won't even compile. So I think the OP didn't post the full script here. The error may be due to the missing part of his/her code.

Comment: thanks @gdlmx, I call like this: `plot_map_from_nc(..., any_time_data=False, ...)`. will change to your suggestion and check

Answer (score 3):

I did a little digging. Sometimes the best place to look is in the code that gave you the error: https://github.com/pallets/click/blob/0d48b2fbd256c1c692e3f3ba4c22b102f21f82f7/click/core.py#L879

```
if args and not ctx.allow_extra_args and not ctx.resilient_parsing:
    ctx.fail('Got unexpected extra argument%s (%s)'
             % (len(args) != 1 and 's' or '',
                ' '.join(map(make_str, args))))
```

So What I think is that you need to set the `allow_extra_args=True` or `resilient_parsing=True`

By default they are:

```
resilient_parsing=False, allow_extra_args=None,
```

https://github.com/pallets/click/blob/0d48b2fbd256c1c692e3f3ba4c22b102f21f82f7/click/core.py#L196

If you want, test it out by commenting out that one, I bet that the error you get will be from `annotate_date` (next alphabetically)

Comment: thanks @busfault, the error message that I am getting is not the same as one you found. My error is `got an unexpected keyword argument` and not `Got unexpected extra argument`. Also commenting out the line you suggested does not do away with the error either

Comment: Thanks! sorry about messing that up!

Comment: thanks @busfault, for looking, i really appreciate that

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to add to @gdlmx's answer because I tried running the code from their answer and ran into errors that took a little bit to parse through. I'd add this as a comment but unfortunately I don't have enough karma.

The code from this block will raise an error: "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" on the last line.

```
def __plot_map_from_nc__(... , any_time_data=True, ...):
    do_your_job_here
# create an alias
plot_map_from_nc = __plot_map_from_nc__ 
# pass this alias to click
@plot_glm.command()
@click.argument('path_nc') # ...
@click.option('--xaxis_min', default=0.0, help='') # ...
plot_map_from_nc
```

The thing that seems to work for this is:

```
#define your original function
def __plot_map_from_nc__(... , any_time_data=True, ...):
    do_your_job_here
#put @ decorator on a regular decorator expression
@plot_glm.command()
@click.argument('path_nc') # ...
@click.option('--xaxis_min', default=0.0, help='') # ...
def plot_map_from_nc(... , any_time_data=True, ...):
    __plot_map_from_nc__(... , any_time_data=True, ...)
```

Basically, this traditional decorator definition gives you a define block to put your @ decorator syntax on. Honestly, this probably isn't the best way to handle this, but because click uses so many decorators for setting up your CLI, it'd be unreasonable to add all of your commands with the traditional syntax.

Comment: This is SO - not reddit - and we use "rep" not "karma" :-)